# Stop rounding values in Qgis attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am calculating the areas of my polygons in Qgis using $area and everything works fine until I click on "save". All my values are rounded to an integer. I tired setting the output field type to decimal but still see the same problem? Any solution to that? I am using Qgis 1.8

Answer (score 3):

Apart from setting the precison to a value greater than zero, I would suggest to increase the field width as well, because the given precision reduces the remaining field width.

A field width of 15 and precision 3 should work well.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP this is the answer that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If I calculate the $area in an integer field I'have got the same result (there is an automatic conversion):

[image]

I think you must specify the "real" type when you create a field  :

[image]

Comment: I thought the same but this behaviour does not change. It still rounds the number...It works if I set it to text but then I am not able to use the numbers for calculations

Comment: it's because, you have to also define the precision (see input below the field type). For example, pass the value to 3 and you will see the change.